# Adding more packages to a wstool generated workspace

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made a source build of hydro using the instructions here (substituting hydro for groovy):

http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source

I followed REP 131 and only made a rosinstall including viz.

However, now I would like to add perception to the workspace.  So I created a new rosinstall as such:

> ~/ros_catkin_ws$ **rosinstall_generator perception --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only > hydro-perception-wet.rosinstall**

> ~/ros_catkin_ws$ **wstool init -j8 src hydro-perception-wet.rosinstall**

But when I tried that I got the following error:

> Error: There already is a workspace config file .rosinstall at "src". Use wstool install/modify.

I tried looking for documentation of wstool here:

http://wiki.ros.org/wstool

But the documentation is sparse.  When I type **wstool help**, I don't see either install or modify as options.

Is there a way to build upon a previous wstool-created workspace or do I need to make a ros_catkin_ws_2 or something like that?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75982/adding-more-packages-to-a-wstool-generated-workspace/) by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on dornhege's answer, I was able to use the following:

> ~/ros_catkin_ws$ **wstool merge hydro-perception-wet.rosinstall -t src**

> ~/ros_catkin_ws$ **wstool update -j 4 -t src**

---

Originally posted by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) with karma: 283 on 2013-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8